# Native Crash | art::MonitorList::SweepMonitorList

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports, android-9.0-pie, temenos-quantum

Below error occurred to multiple users but once mostly per device. But it continuous to happen.
 
I have not used App bundle, but provided 2 separate APK for 32 bit and 64 bit phones.
All devices mentioned so far are at Android 9 level.
My build is taken with target SDK API 26 (due to the limitation present in Kony IDE). compiled using API 28.

What may cause this error?
I am unable to reproduce this issue. Any probable cause for this issue?

**Devices in which this observed:**
Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018) (a7y18lte), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy Note10+ (d2s), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy S10 (beyond1), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy S10+ (beyond2), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy Note9 (crownlte), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy Note8 (greatlte), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy S10 (beyond1), Android 9
Huawei P20 Pro (HWCLT), Android 9
Huawei P30 Pro (HWVOG), Android 9
Huawei Mate 20 Pro (HWLYA), Android 9

**Error From Google Play Console**

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 

backtrace:


  #00  pc 00000000003c3ef8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::MonitorList::SweepMonitorList(art::IsMarkedVisitor*)+288)


  #01  pc 0000000000469874  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::SweepSystemWeaks(art::IsMarkedVisitor*)+40)


  #02  pc 00000000001c1824  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::SweepSystemWeaks(art::Thread*)+192)


  #03  pc 00000000001be504  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::MarkingPhase()+1928)


  #04  pc 00000000001bc8b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::RunPhases()+1328)


  #05  pc 00000000001d2be8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::GarbageCollector::Run(art::gc::GcCause, bool)+320)


  #06  pc 00000000001f5594  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+3408)


  #07  pc 0000000000206b10  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+128)


  #08  pc 000000000020c178  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGCTask::Run(art::Thread*)+40)


  #09  pc 000000000022ebb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+68)


  #10  pc 000000000007b56c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.VMRuntime.clampGrowthLimit [DEDUPED]+124)


  #11  pc 00000000001845d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal+196)


  #12  pc 0000000000111e7c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+76)


  #13  pc 000000000025d068  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)


  #14  pc 000000000055ab88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)


  #15  pc 00000000000d04c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)


  #16  pc 00000000004618ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)


  #17  pc 0000000000462968  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)


  #18  pc 000000000048dd88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)


  #19  pc 00000000000836c8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+196)


  #20  pc 0000000000023bac  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Comment: I also have the same issue on Android 9. seems it's related to the GC of the ART.
I didn't figure out the solution yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.